# Can't make Emblem.js work with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, emblem.js

I'm trying to use Emblem.js to render Ember templates in a Rails app. Here is a part of my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.9.0'
gem 'emblem-rails'
gem 'emblem-source', github: 'machty/emblem.js'
```

This is according to the installation instructions of `emblem-rails` gem: https://github.com/alexspeller/emblem-rails

I have a very basic app. This is the layout written in slim:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title My App Title
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  body
```

I also have a basic Ember-Rails app where I have my application template written with emblem `/app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.emblem`:

```
h1 Hello World
```

But I get the following error (even after restarting my puma server):

```
ArgumentError at /
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
  (in /Users/htaidirt/Code/MyApp/app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.emblem)
```

with a highlight to the layout at `= javascript_include_tag 'application'` line: https://www.dropbox.com/s/un8ixkpgvn81txi/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-29%20at%2019.00.46.png?dl=0?dl=1

Do you have any idea how can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved with

gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

gem 'ember-rails', '~> 0.19.0'

gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.13.5'

gem 'ember-emblem-template'

gem 'emblem-source', '~> 0.4'

Comment: Thanks @Alexandr, it works. But now I'm getting 4 warnings (deprecations) in my console: `DEPRECATION: Using 'Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper' is deprecated`, `DEPRECATION: Using Ember.HTMLBars._registerHelper is deprecated`, `DEPRECATION: Using 'Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper' is deprecated` and `DEPRECATION: Using Ember.HTMLBars._registerHelper is deprecated`

Comment: thanks for pointing `gem 'ember-emblem-template'`, it helps without downgrading sprockets